# Is there a way out to install Jenkins-Operator on powerPC (ppc64le) architecture?

Tags: jenkins-kubernetes

I'm trying to install jenkins-operator on kubernetes on power (ppc64le) architecture, but I haven't found any suitable image of jenkins-operator to install on power architecture. Is there a way to install it on power?

If there is a way out to install it or if anyone has already tried to install on power, please give me some pointers.